# Change shazam language

Tags: iphone, language

My phone language is English, but in some apps (like Shazam) the language is Russian. I guess it’s because of my geographical location, but it shouldn’t be like that as my phone language is English. How can I change the language of such apps?

Comment: Actually, I think that the only solution is to contact Shazam's support. As a developer I think that's a pretty weird way to handle languages btw..The other solution would be to switch to another app like SoundHound.

Comment: Have you checked in Settings > Shazam to see if their is a language item?  But yes, apps should normally always take the language of the OS (unless it is one for which the app has not been localized).

Comment: Also, maybe good to know: this will be fixed in iOS 13! You will be able to change the language for any app in Settings.